# Modular multiplication of co-primes – always unique?

Tags: modular-arithmetic, coprime

I am following the blog post "[A practical use of multiplicative inverses](https://ericlippert.com/2013/11/14/a-practical-use-of-multiplicative-inverses/)" to implement a pseudo-hash function that needs to be reversible. The idea works perfectly, but I would like to understand in more detail how the results can be provably unique – and unfortunately my ability falls short.

Ignoring the inverse element, I would like to understand how for any input (up to $m$), the result will be unique.

The important excerpt from the blog post is as follows:

> Start by picking a large number $m$, much larger than the number of tokens you’re ever going to need to generate. Let’s say 1000000000. Now pick any number $x$ coprime to that; lets say 387420489.

> $encoded = invoiceNumber \times 387420489 \bmod 1000000000$

> This gives us a unique random-seeming number between 0 and 999999999. We know the number will be different for every input.

I would like to understand *why* the encoded number will be different for every input.

Thanks in advance